# Evaluate the limit integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am doing this exercises, but I am stuck.
I have to evaluate this limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)dx
$$
where $f_n(x)=(1+\frac{2x}{n})^ne^{-x^2}$.

I have seen that $f_n(x)\to e^{2x-x^2}$, so my idea is to use the dominated convergence theorem.
The problem is that I am not able to find a function $g(x)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is integrable.

Could you give me some advices on which $g$ to use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why can't you just use $g(x) = e^{2x-x^2}$?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f_n(x)| \leq e^{2|x|-x^{2}}$ which is integrable. [$(1+\frac a n)^{n} \leq e^{a}$ for all $a >0$].